# 7-zip extraction using multiple cores?

Tags: 7z, p7zip

I have `stuff.7z.001`  to `stuff.7z.007`.  They are big.

Is there a way to `7z x` in Linux to take advantage of multiple cores and speed things up?

also, how does one run the 7-zip gui in rhel/centos 7 ?  I have `p7zip-gui-16.02-20.el7.x86_64` installed but I can't find a corresponding *7-zip gui* entry under the applications menu nor know the command line command to kick off the gui.

Comment: In windows I see it using 2 cores to extract 7z files by default; it uses more cores during creation.

Answer (score 4):

Your post includes multiple questions and some of them are outside the scope of this SE which is not welcomed but whatever:

1. 7z decompression is single threaded and that's the limitation of the compression format, there's nothing that can be done to "fix" that. Multiple 7z volumes are not separate archives, it's one continuous archive split in parts.
2. p7zip is terribly outdated and hasn't been actively maintained, nowadays there's [native 7zz](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/21.07/) (`7z2107-src.7z` is sources, `7z2107-linux-XX.tar.xz` is a binary for a sufficiently fresh Linux distro) from Igor Pavlov himself.
3. Neither p7zip, nor 7zz have GUI, if you need that you may run [PeaZip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PeaZip) or Windows 7-zip under Wine.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to 7z x in Linux to take advantage of multiple cores and speed things up?

As far as I can tell, `7z` does't do multithreaded decompression; it does multithread compression (by default even), so that's a bit surprising. However, it'd probably gain very little: on my system, for most things I'm mostly IO bound, not CPU bound (decompression only takes ~ 60% of one core when writing to an nvme SSD).

> know the command line command to kick off the gui.

```
7zG
```

(found via `rpm -ql p7zip-gui`)

Comment: all I get from running `7zG` is a popup window saying *Specify Command*

Comment: well you need to specify the operation you want 7zG to do.