# How can I multithreadedly extract several 7z archives into their own folder, using the archive name as the folder name?

Tags: gnu-parallel, 7z

To extract all 7z archives into their own folder, using the archive name as the folder name, I run the command:

```
7z x "*.7z" -o*
```

E.g., if one has the two files `a.7z` and `b.7z`, then folders `a` and `b` will be created and they'll contain the content of `a.7z` and `b.7z` (keeping the directory structure), respectively.

Sometimes, I have many 7z archives, and I'd like to extract them using multiple cores. I read this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/690784/16704) by [Artem S. Tashkinov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/260833/artem-s-tashkinov):

> 7z decompression is single threaded and that's the limitation of the compression format

Therefore, I am looking at using `parallel`, since in my case I have multiple 7z archives.

I tried:

```
parallel -j4 '7z x {} -o{}' ::: *.7z
```

However, if we go back to the example with the two files `a.7z` and `b.7z`, the command will try to extract the two files `a.7z` and `b.7z` to the folders `a.7z` and `b.7z` instead of `a` and `b`, which will crash the execution since `a.7z` and `b.7z` are already taken and are files. How can I fix that? I want to have two folders, `a` and `b`.

If that matters, I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

`parallel` drops the extension if you specify `{.}` instead of `{}`:

```
parallel -j4 '7z x {} -o{.}' ::: *.7z
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note, about the `*` in `-o{dir_path}` option. The documentation states that

> `{dir_path}`
> This is the destination directory path [...] If you specify `*` in `{dir_path}`, 7-Zip substitutes that `*` character to archive name.

The proper syntax for your initial command is

```
7z x \*.7z -o\*
```

that is, the second `*` has to be escaped as well otherwise the shell will try to expand it. You're probably using `bash` without the `nullglob` option that's why it works (it can't find a match so it passes it literally to `7z`)...

---

Now, to run that command via `gnu parallel` you could either use `*` (escaped, as I said above):

```
parallel -j4 '7z x {} -o\*' ::: *.7z
```

or drop the `*` and use `parallel` replacement string `{.}` as in Stephen's answer.